# Как достаточно быстро записать огромное число в txt файл

Tags: python, biginteger

У меня есть алгоритм в котором в итоге получается гигантский int больше чем 10^500000000 (само число считается относительно быстро за 2 часа на 20 ядрах) проблема заключается в том что мне нужно записать это число в txt файл в 10 системе счисления. И вот эта стадия занимает очень много времени(жду уже 3 день). Я использую pickle для записи в файл. Из всех методов что я пробовал pickle оказался быстрее всего

```
file = open("110.txt",'w')
pickle.dump(chislo, file, 0)
file.close()
```

Если использовать dump протокол 2 (pickle.dump(chislo, file, 2) то запись происходит быстро, но запись происходит не в 10 системе, а в другом виде. Да я знаю можно будет потом её считать обратно. Но моя цель это что-бы в итого в txt было число в 10 системе счисления.

Comment: _моя цель ... число в 10 системе_ - нафиг такую цель. Человекочитаемый формат нужен - кто бы мог подумать? - для чтения человеком (и только). Но всё равно никто не сможет прочитать такое большое число. Так что пишите в том формате, который быстро обрабатывается машиной. Слава роботам!

Comment: Я боюсь он число в десятичку преобразует делением на 10. а это дико медленно. Вам бы отдельно реализовать https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble лучше конечно на C и потом как то подключить к питону (из BCD печатать просто, берем 4 бита, добавляем 0x30 вот и получили символ, переходим к следующим 4)

Comment: а в каком виде/формате у вас сейчас число и как вы его пытаетесь записать в файл сейчас?

Comment: для чисел со многими числами можно [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mpz.html) использовать. Связанный вопрос: [Writing huge strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28420541/4279)